# ExtJs 4.2 error 'getById called for ID that is not present in local cache' when refreshing the gird

Tags: javascript, rest, extjs, extjs4.2

Here is what I have:
[image]

When clicking on one of the boxes the list below gets filtered on the server side.

If I select on of the rows in the grid and then commit a filter, I get the following error:

*"getById called for ID that is not present in local cache"*

[image]

This gets raised even if the filter does include the record that I have selected.

Here is the module:

```
Ext.define('NG.model.auxClasses.notifications.WhatsNew', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'iD',
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: [
        { name: 'iD', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'isActive', type: 'boolean' },
        { name: 'documentIdentifier', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'sourceSiteName', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'targetSiteName', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'createDate', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'c' },
        { name: 'businessArchiveEvent', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'businessArchive', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'previousWhatsNewEvents' },
        { name: 'isPin', type: 'boolean' },
        { name: 'IsDocumentReadByMe', type: 'boolean' },
        { name: 'isDocumentReadByOthers', type: 'boolean' },
        { name: 'documentYear', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'businessDirection', type:'int'}
    ],

    // self association model
    associations: [{
        type: 'hasMany',
        model: 'auxClasses.notifications.WhatsNew',
        name: 'previousWhatsNewEvents',
        primaryKey: 'id',
        associationKey: 'previousWhatsNewEvents'
    }],

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'api/WhatsNew/'
    }

});
```

Here is the store:

```
Ext.define('NG.store.WhatsNews', {
    extend: 'NG.store.AbstractStore',
    model: 'NG.model.auxClasses.notifications.WhatsNew',
    alias: 'store.whatsnewstore',
    autoLoad:true,
    buffered: true,
    pageSize: 50
});
```

**UPDATE:**

I have followed the rabbit to the hole and found a workaround that I am not sure will work:

Here is where I failing:

```
refresh: function() {
        ...

        // Don't need to do this on the first refresh
        if (me.hasFirstRefresh) {
        // Some subclasses do not need to do this. TableView does not need to do this.                   
               if (me.refreshSelmodelOnRefresh !== false) {
                    me.selModel.refresh();
                } else {
                    // However, even if that is not needed, pruning if pruneRemoved is true (the default) still needs doing.
                    me.selModel.pruneIf(); <<< HERE WE FAIL. THIS METHODS CALLS THE GET BY ID
                }
            }

           ...
    }
```

So on my view I have added the following view config:

```
viewConfig: {
        refreshSelmodelOnRefresh:true // Workaround : if this is not set to true when the grid will refresh and a record will be selected we will get an ext error 
    },
```

This has solved the error being raised, but I am unsure of the end result and what it might harm later on.

If someone can shade some light...

Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do-

1. Increase your pageSize to at least 100, a buffered store is not really designed for small recordsets
2. Use the below override:

This override fixes multiple bugs when store is a buffered type and fixed a bug that causes the initial hasId to not work because the store.getById() method expects an ID and not the record, also forcing the double verification when the record is not found because it places both checks in a single if statement.

@src: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?258397-4.2.0-RC-Selecting-a-grid-s-row-with-a-buffered-store-causes-a-JavaScript-error/page2

```
 Ext.override(Ext.selection.Model, {
  storeHasSelected: function(record) {
    var store = this.store,
        records,
        len, id, i, m;

    if (record.hasId()) {
        return store.getById(record.getId());
    } else {
        if (store.buffered) {//on buffered stores the map holds the data items
            records = [];
            for (m in store.data.map) {
                records = records.concat(store.data.map[m].value);
            }
        } else {
            records = store.data.items;
        }
        len = records.length;
        id = record.internalId;


        for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            if (id === records[i].internalId) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

If neither 1 nor 2 work, try:

```
Ext.view.AbstractView.override({
    refresh: function() {
        var me = this,
            targetEl,
            targetParent,
            oldDisplay,
            nextSibling,
            dom,
            records;

        if (!me.rendered || me.isDestroyed) {
            return;
        }

        if (!me.hasListeners.beforerefresh || me.fireEvent('beforerefresh', me) !== false) {
            targetEl = me.getTargetEl();
            records = me.getViewRange();
            dom = targetEl.dom;

            // Updating is much quicker if done when the targetEl is detached from the document, and not displayed.
            // But this resets the scroll position, so when preserving scroll position, this cannot be done.
            if (!me.preserveScrollOnRefresh) {
                targetParent = dom.parentNode;
                oldDisplay = dom.style.display;
                dom.style.display = 'none';
                nextSibling = dom.nextSibling;
                targetParent.removeChild(dom);
            }

            if (me.refreshCounter) {
                me.clearViewEl();
            } else {
                me.fixedNodes = targetEl.dom.childNodes.length;
                me.refreshCounter = 1;
            }

            // Always attempt to create the required markup after the fixedNodes.
            // Usually, for an empty record set, this would be blank, but when the Template
            // Creates markup outside of the record loop, this must still be honoured even if there are no
            // records.
            me.tpl.append(targetEl, me.collectData(records, me.all.startIndex));

            // The emptyText is now appended to the View's element
            // after any fixedNodes.


            if (typeof records !== 'undefined' && records !== undefined && records && records.length < 1) { 
                // Process empty text unless the store is being cleared.
                if (!this.store.loading && (!me.deferEmptyText || me.hasFirstRefresh)) {
                    Ext.core.DomHelper.insertHtml('beforeEnd', targetEl.dom, me.emptyText);
                }
                me.all.clear();
            } else {
                me.collectNodes(targetEl.dom);
                me.updateIndexes(0);
            }

            // Don't need to do this on the first refresh
            if (me.hasFirstRefresh) {
                // Some subclasses do not need to do this. TableView does not need to do this.
                if (me.refreshSelmodelOnRefresh !== false) {
                    me.selModel.refresh();
                } else {
                    // However, even if that is not needed, pruning if pruneRemoved is true (the default) still needs doing.
                    me.selModel.pruneIf();
                }
            }

            me.hasFirstRefresh = true;

            if (!me.preserveScrollOnRefresh) {
                targetParent.insertBefore(dom, nextSibling);
                dom.style.display = oldDisplay;
            }

            // Ensure layout system knows about new content size
            this.refreshSize();

            me.fireEvent('refresh', me);

            // Upon first refresh, fire the viewready event.
            // Reconfiguring the grid "renews" this event.
            if (!me.viewReady) {
                // Fire an event when deferred content becomes available.
                // This supports grid Panel's deferRowRender capability
                me.viewReady = true;
                me.fireEvent('viewready', me);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my code ,I used bufferd store with a grid,then I get this error.

I solved it with this

```
selModel: {
    pruneRemoved: false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this override

```
    Ext.data.Store.override({
        getById: function(id) {
            var result = (this.snapshot || this.data).findBy(function(record) {
                return record.getId() === id;
            });
            if (this.buffered && !result) {
                return [];
            }
            return result;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For ExtJS 5 override BufferedStore instead of Store:

```
Ext.data.BufferedStore.override({
    getById: function(id) {
        var result = (this.snapshot || this.data).findBy(function(record) {
            return record.getId() === id;
        });
        if (this.buffered && !result) {
            return [];
        }
        return result;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any of the aforementioned overrides. If you get this error when using a buffered store, simply set the pruneRemoved: false property as specified here:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-cfg-pruneRemoved

e.g.

```
selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.RowModel', {
                pruneRemoved: false
})
```